# Encounter npm problem when deploy composer network to channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

When I deploy a composer network to a existing channel, it encountered a npm problem which is:

```
Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 1 "npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.3.3: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: composer-common@0.20.2 (node_modules/composer-common):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: 504 Gateway Time-out: composer-common@0.20.2

npm ERR! code E504
npm ERR! 504 Gateway Time-out: composer-runtime-hlfv1@0.20.2

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-11-27T08_24_53_766Z-debug.log
"
```

My Fabric Version is 1.2.0 And Composer Version is 0.20.2.

I am in China and I have modified my fabric-ccenv's npm registry to one souce which server can connect directly.

This problem will be sovled when I restart the docker swarm.

Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

Comment: I assume this is an error with `composer network start`?  Have you seen the option to use an npmrc file on the `composer network install command`? It is described in the Composer Knowledge Wiki: https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#information_source--composer-network-install-issues

Comment: Yes, it occured in start one network , I'll try to follow the guidance